# lightslider jQuery doesn't show full height glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We're using the lightslider plugin for product images. The issue is that in Safari and sometimes in Chrome (especially on mobile), on load the whole slider will be hidden and only showing ~30px.

Tried setting the min-height:1px and setting the width/height on of the images but that didn't work.

Looking with inspector, the slider is adding:

```css
ul#web-slider.lightSlider{
  height: 0px;
}
```

And any height style I set doesn't fix it.

[See it live here](https://www.medsitemedical.com/medical-website-design/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I'm getting an index undefined error in chrome saying `jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: This popped up when we added the new jquery. Not sure about this either.

Comment: Was this ever solved?